# Renumber contiguous equal values in a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `A` in Matlab of dimension `MxN` with the following structure

```
A=[23  10 3;
   23  4  5;
   456 6  8;
   456 8  9;
   456 12 14;
   5   56 32]
```

The key characteristic of `A` is that in the first column there are some values repeated a certain (not fixed) number of times: in the example `23` is repeated twice, `456` is repeated 3 times, `3` is repeated once.

I would like some advice to write a piece of code replacing `23` with `1`, `456` with `2`, `5` with `3` so that I transform `A` into

```
A=[1 10 3;
   1 4  5;
   2 6  8;
   2 8  9;
   2 12 14;
   3 56 32]
```

This code does what I want but it contains a double loop that I would like to avoid

```
   C=unique(A(:,1),'stable');
   for j=1:size(C,1)
       for h=1:size(A,1)
           if A(h,1)==C(j)
               A(h,1)=j;
           end
       end
   end
```

Comment: Use third output of the `unique` function : `[~,~,u] = unique(A(:,1),'stable');A(:,1)=u;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unique` as suggested by rahnema. From the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) we can get more insight:

> [C,ia,ic] = unique(A) also returns index vectors ia and ic.
>   - If A is a matrix or array, then `C = A(ia)` and `A(:) = C(ic)`.

Which means that `ic`, the third output, returns which row of the unique vector `C` corresponds to the given row of `A`. In particular, you will want to use the `'stable'` argument to keep the same order, otherwise the indices will also be sorted with respect to the unique values.

---

So, **in summary**, assign the third output of `unique` to the first column of `A`.

```
[~, ~, A(:,1)] = unique(A(:,1), 'stable');
```

Output:

```
>> A =

 1    10     3
 1     4     5
 2     6     8
 2     8     9
 2    12    14
 3    56    32
```